# How to release SemaphoreSlim?

Tags: c#, locking, semaphore

I am using `SemaphoreSlim` as my lock mechanism. in my code i don't know for releasing the semaphore which code is more efficient?
this is semaphore instantiation:

```
 private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _updateTokenLocker = new (1, 1);
```

the first code:

```
await _updateTokenLocker.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow >= _tokenExpirationDateTime.AddMinutes(-5))
                {
                    var newToken = await GetTokenAsync();
                    return newToken;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _updateTokenLocker.Release();
            }
```

or this code:

```
await _updateTokenLocker.WaitAsync();
                if (DateTime.UtcNow >= _tokenExpirationDateTime.AddMinutes(-5))
                {
                    var newToken = await GetTokenAsync();
                   _updateTokenLocker.Release();
                    return newToken;
                }
```

Comment: Before considering efficiency you have to consider correctness. What will happen in the 2nd snippet if there is an exception before `_updateTokenLocker.Release();` is called ?

Comment: _“which code is more efficient?"_ Why can't you test it yourself?

Comment: Do you mean I have to use try catch finally?@wohlstad

Comment: @Neg see the posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the second one will be more "efficient" since it will need to perform less operations, but this does not matter, because it is incorrect implementation - in case of an exception the semaphore will not be released, so you should not even consider it as an option.

P.S.

The difference of `try-finally` should be negligible, especially compared to async handling.

The following simple benchmark (via [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)):

```cs
public class TryFinallyBench
{
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _updateTokenLocker = new(1, 1);

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task Tryf()
    {
        await _updateTokenLocker.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        finally
        {
            _updateTokenLocker.Release();
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task NoTryf()
    {
        await _updateTokenLocker.WaitAsync();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        _updateTokenLocker.Release();
    }
}
```

Gives on my machine:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tryf | 48.22 ns | 0.785 ns | 0.696 ns |
| NoTryf | 47.70 ns | 0.953 ns | 0.891 ns |